# Rxjs: unable to access array elements in subscribe

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, angularfire2

I am retrieving an AngularFireStoreCollection in my Ionic app using following

```
this.analysisProvider.getAllOrders().valueChanges()
 .map(ordercoll=>ordercoll)
 .pipe(mergeMap(orddoc=>orddoc)).map(ord=>ord.orderdetails).map(res=>res)
 .subscribe(val=>{
 console.log('res=',val);  
})
```

The console.log gives following output
[image: Console Image]

Now I actually want to access the partprice property , apply filters and reduce to get a total value from all the documents . However I am not able to access anything from val value in the subscribe function. I tried following in subscribe

1. console.log('val=',val.partprice);
   output: val=undefined
2. val.forEach(v=> console.log('val=',v.partprice));
   output: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{ partname: string; partcode: string; quantity: number; revisedquantity: number; duedate: any; re...'.

I am not sure what else I should do.
Ideally I would like to map filter and reduce before the subscribe and use subscribe only to assign the final output to a variable. Any suggestions to achieve that are most welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

val is an array of items, and you're trying to access a property on the items IN the array.  You're looking for `console.log(val[0].partprice)` or `val.forEach(item => console.log(item.partPrice))`

Comment: I cannot use val[0].partprice as there could be multiple. Already tried val.forEach(item => console.log(item.partPrice)). Getting error : Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{ partname: string; partcode: string; quantity: number; revisedquantity: number; duedate: any; re...'.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
...
.flatMap(order => order)
.map(order => order.partprice)
.filter(price => price > 0)
.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value)
.subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

The Observable has to complete to make reduce work.
Flat map maps the arrays to single events so that they can be processed by reactive functions.

Comment: This is how I actually started but got errors and diverted to other options. Errors: Typescript Error on flatmap
Argument of type '(order: { partname: string; partcode: string; ...' is not assignable to parameter{  AND typescript error on map Property 'partprice' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: What type does analysisProvider.getAllOrders().valueChanges return??
It should be something like:
    Observable<Order[]>

Comment: The chain on valueChanges() returns an array in an intermediate step. I assigned an  array variable till that point and processed the array at the required stage with map/filter/reduce. This solved the issue. Thanks for your inputs.